Meta-Analysis - Correctly treat multiple conditions in within study designs
we are currently conducting a systematic review and meta-analysis and are unsure how to deal with multiple effects from one and the same study.
We are running a basic hierarcical three-level model where the highest level in the hierarcy is "study" (i.e. outcomes are nested within studies). We have quite a number of studies that report either more than one intervention or more than one control group/condition of interest.
As far as we know for between-study designs it is recommended to combine groups, select just one comparison or split the shared groups into several groups with smaller sample sizes (https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_5_4_how_to_include_multiple_groups_from_one_study.htm). For us the last option is the most appealing one.
However, we are unaware of how to deal with the same problem in within-study designs. We have several within-studies that also have more than two (always counterbalanced) conditions, so several combinations of comparisons that are interesting for us. Do we follow the same approach here i.e. reduce the N of the study per included effect by dividing it by number of included effects?
Or is all of this not necessary for a hierarcical three-level model anyway because we account for nested effects within studies?
Thanks a lot!

I would suggest that if you fit a multi-level model you have the advantage of (a) including all the variability including at the lowest level (b) you have the possibility of including moderators at lower levels. So I would fit a multi-level model. I do not know of studies which have compared the approaches which is why this is just a comment not an answer.

in my understanding we already fit a multi-level model (three-level). i was under the impression that we still have to account for the biased sample size somehow (e.g. if we have a study with two interventions (A, B) and one control (C) and we use the comparisons A-C and B-C, the doubled sample size of the control group would be included, which is of course not the way to go). but maybe i am mistaken?

That sounds like a candidate for network meta-analysis especially if not all treatments appear in all studies. You said it was a within subject design, does that mean everybody did all three treatments?

Interesting. I will check out the network meta-analytical approach. yes, not all treatments appear in all studies, in fact the specifics of the treatments have substantial heterogneity. and yes, some of the studies are within subject designs, meaning that each participants is exposed to each treatment.
